# How can I cancel an active boto3 s3 file_download?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm using boto3 to download files from an s3 bucket & I need to support canceling an active file transfer in my client UI - but I can't find how to do it.

There is a progress callback that I can use for transfer status, but I can not cancel the transfer from there.

I did find that boto3's `s3transfer.TransferManager` object has a `.shutdown()` member, but it is buggy (.shutdown() passes the wrong params to ._shutdown() a few lines below it) & crashes.

Is there another way to safely cancel an active file_download?

Answer (score 4):

I apologize as I do not have enough rep to post a comment, I wanted to point you towards the [S3Control](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3control.html#S3Control.Client.update_job_status) docs, as it appears that you *might* be able to schedule the download operations as jobs and then also use `update_job_status(**kwargs)` to cancel the job should it no longer be needed. I have not tested this, so feel free to downvote if not useful.

edit: I have enough rep to comment on future questions, thanks fam.

Comment: Did this approach work?

Answer (score 1):

Can you kill the process associated with the file?

`kill $(ps -ef | grep 'process-name' | awk '{print $2}')`